# How can I write a tactic which works both in a goal and a hypothesis?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to write a tactic which can work on goals and hypothesis similar to `symmetry`, but for inequalities as well. Now, there is some [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html) on generalized rewriting, but this is very advanced and perhaps should be a different question. That said, here is my implementation which works (albeit awkwardly) for my use case:

```
Require Import Coq.PArith.BinPos.

Ltac symmetry' :=
  lazymatch goal with
  | [ |- ?x <> ?y ] => unfold not; intros NQ; symmetry in NQ; revert NQ
  | [ |- _ ] => symmetry
  end.

Lemma succ_discr' : forall p : positive,
  Pos.succ p <> p.
Proof.
  intros p.
  symmetry'.
  apply Pos.succ_discr.
Qed.
```

This is fine, but what if we have an inequality in the hypothesis we wish to apply `symmetry'` to?

```
Lemma succ_discr' : forall p : positive,
  Pos.succ p <> p -> (2 * p <> Pos.succ (2 * p))%positive.
Proof.
  intros p H.
  Fail symmetry' in H.
  (* Fails with Error:
Syntax error: [tactic:ltac_use_default] expected after [tactic:tactic] (in [vernac:tactic_command]). *)
```

I tried writing

```
Ltac symmetry'' H :=
  lazymatch H with
   | ?x <> ?y => unfold not; intros NQ; symmetry in NQ; revert NQ
   | _ => symmetry
   end.
```

then applying via `symmetry'' H` but that failed with another error,

```
Error:
Tactic failure:  The relation (fun x y : positive => x <> y) is not a
declared symmetric relation. Maybe you need to require the
Coq.Classes.RelationClasses library.
```

So, my question is, is there something special about the builtin `symmetry` tactic which allows it to be used with the `in` keyword, or do I just need to write my Ltac in a particular way to be able to use `in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ltac symmetry' :=
  lazymatch goal with
  | [ |- ?x <> ?y ] => apply not_eq_sym
  | [ |- _ ] => symmetry
  end.

Ltac symmetry'' H :=
  lazymatch type of H with
   | ?x <> ?y => apply not_eq_sym in H
   | _ => symmetry in H
   end.
```

Note that you need to match on `type of H`, not on `H` itself (since it's going to be a variable).

> is there something special about the builtin symmetry tactic which allows it to be used with the in keyword, or do I just need to write my Ltac in a particular way to be able to use in?

The `in` variant of a tactic can be defined as a `Tactic Notation` (i.e., it's really a separate thing from the original tactic).

```
Tactic Notation "symmetry'" "in" ident(H) := symmetry'' H.
(* symmetry' in H *)
```